# How to pass viewcontroller name in function parameters?

Tags: ios, swift, function, alert

```
func showalertOkayButton(message: String?, identifier: string?, viewControllerName: UIViewController){

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: kMessage, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
       let defaultaction = UIAlertAction(title: kOkay, style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler:{ defaultaction in
        let VC = UIStoryboard(name: kMainStoryBoard, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as! viewControllerName
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
    })
    alertController.addAction(defaultaction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

so my question is i can't send the `viewControllerName` it's giving me error "used of undeclared" so how can i send the view controller name in function.
well this is for learning purpose sorry if i asking wrong thing.
so please guide me or help me
Thank in advacne.

Comment: Swift is static, not dynamic. All types have to be known in advance. You cannot pass an unknown type and say “cast to this type” at runtime. But you don’t need to! Just strip out the stuff about the view controller name. You can push a view controller without knowing its type. It’s a view controller!  The compiler knows that, and that’s all it needs to know.

Comment: @matt you are incorrect. How do you think `Any`, `as`, and `type(of:)` work if Swift doesn't have dynamic type information?

Comment: @matt there is nothing we can do for that how about if i'm sending on UIViewController type.

Comment: @Max I'm not incorrect. You cannot cast an Any down to `type(of: something)` or to `SomeType` (where SomeType is a variable). The compiler has to be told _at compile time_ what type you propose to cast down to. You can only cast down to a _literal_ type (or, using a generic, to a _constrained_ type — but in the case of a generic, the type is known _in advance_ once again).

Comment: @matt true, but that's not what the asker wants. They just want to define `something` as a function parameter, which _is_ possible thanks to generics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how `as` works. In `x as! y`, y is not a *name* it is a *type*. And when you have `viewControllerName: UIViewController` as a function parameter, that is not passing a *name* that is passing an *instance* of the UIViewController *type*. So if you want to specify what that `as` is casting to, you need to pass a *type* as your function parameter. Using generics, that looks like this:

```
func showalertOkayButton<T: UIViewController>(message: String?, identifier: String, viewControllerType: T.Type) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: kMessage, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let defaultaction = UIAlertAction(title: kOkay, style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler:{ defaultaction in
        let VC = UIStoryboard(name: kMainStoryBoard, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as! T
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
    })

    alertController.addAction(defaultaction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Calling it would look like this

```
showalertOkayButton("Message", "VCIdentifier", MyViewController.self)
```

However, none of this is necessary in your specific case. Swift is a dynamic language, so when you instantiate a view controller from a storyboard it can load its dynamic type information at runtime. However the *compiler* doesn't know what type it is so it gives you a simple `UIViewController` instance as a result. It is not necessary to cast it using `as` until the moment you need to call specific methods on that view controller that don't exist in the `UIViewController` superclass.

Even if you don't cast it, it will continue to behave correctly thanks to polymorphism. So you can shorten your code to this

```
func showalertOkayButton(message: String?, identifier: String) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: kMessage, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let defaultaction = UIAlertAction(title: kOkay, style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler:{ defaultaction in
        let VC = UIStoryboard(name: kMainStoryBoard, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
    })

    alertController.addAction(defaultaction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Swift is static, not dynamic. All types have to be known in advance. You cannot pass an unknown type and say “cast to this type” at runtime. But you don’t need to! Just strip out the stuff about the view controller "name" (actually its class). You can push a view controller without knowing its specific class. It’s a view controller! The compiler knows that, and that’s all it needs to know. Just delete your stuff about the view controller's type, and all will be well.

```
func showalertOkayButton(message: String?, identifier: String)
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: kMessage, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let defaultaction = UIAlertAction(title: kOkay, style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler:{ defaultaction in
        let VC = UIStoryboard(name: kMainStoryBoard, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
    })
    alertController.addAction(defaultaction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help your code also work for me.